# Expandable List View not working properly

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I'm trying to make a simple media player app using an expandable list view to display names of songs and heading being their folder name. The problem is when the app runs, I open an expandable list & only the first child view works while the others don't.

```
  expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView expandableListView, View view, int i, int i1, long l) {

                final int a = i;
                final int b = i1;

                TextView txtListChild = (TextView) expandableListView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
                ImageView img = (ImageView)expandableListView.findViewById(R.id.img);


                txtListChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting Music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            String s = mapping.get(headers.get(a));

                            String path = s+"/"+inner.get(headers.get(a)).get(b)+".mp3";

                            Uri myUri = Uri.parse(path);
                            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myUri);
                            mediaPlayer.prepare();
                            mediaPlayer.start();

                        }
                        catch (Exception e){
                            Log.i("Exception",e.toString());
                        }

                    }
                });

                img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Stopping Music", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        if(mediaPlayer!=null){
                            mediaPlayer.stop();
                        }

                    }
                });
                return false;
        }
    });
```

This is the code where I add onChild click listener to my main activity, and my child view has a `TextView` and an `ImageView`. Only the child at position 0 works, the rest don't.

If any other code snippet is required, please mention it in a comment.

This is the XML for the Child Object

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Song Name"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/img"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_name"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT: 
code for adapter ->

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, List<String>> _listDataChild;

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,//ArrayList<Pojo> list,
                             HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(i)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int i) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(i);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int i, int i1) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(i)).get(i1);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
    return i1;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                                                                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.heading_expandable, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                                                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_expandable, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
    txtListChild.setText(childText);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
    return true;
}
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code of adapter class ??

Comment: @Pritish done, added code in edit & thnx

Comment: What do you exactly mean when you say only first child view works ? Like only it gets clicked, or only one child is displayed ??

Comment: only 1st child item upon click plays music while the rest are inactive

Comment: Just try one thing, remove those click listeners inside the onchildclick for image view and text view temporarily, ie comment that code,and please let me know if clicks are simply working for child, ie put a toast in onchildclick and please see if log or toast is firing for every child

Comment: if I remove the rest & add code then it works fine

Comment: Try setting your onclick listener of individual view inside getChildView() method inside adapter instead of onchildClick and do let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178123/discussion-between-pritish-and-anjani-mittal).

Comment: In my case only one item get displayed and the rest are not displaying leaving the layout empty